# Can I use a strong alcoholic drink (40 % of ethanol) to disinfect frequently touched surfaces against COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, alcohol, disinfection

Can I use a strong alcoholic drink (containing mostly water and 40 % of ethyl alcohol) to disinfect the frequently touched surfaces indoors or even packed food items I buy in the supermarket)?

Vodka is still available at the shop, and the proper disinfecting fluid is not. I talked about external usage, I do not even think to drink it. Would it work at least in some degree?

Comment: No you can't and the answer is also here https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21453/can-i-make-a-hand-sanitiser-with-reagent-grade-ethanol-99-8-v-v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40% alcohol is probably too dilute for disinfection. According to the CDC, minimum concentrations for sanitization with alcohol are 60% for ethanol or 70% for isopropanol (https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/hcp/hand-hygiene.html?CDC_AA_refVal=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cdc.gov%2Fcoronavirus%2F2019-ncov%2Finfection-control%2Fhcp-hand-sanitizer.html) .